# Are there other image file format that are fast and can be used as intermediary file for conversion jsimilar to MIFF file?

Tags: ghostscript

I want to convert an EPS file to MIFF file using GhostScript. But standard GhostScript installation in Windows 10 does not include miff24 device. This miff24 device is used by GS to convert to MIFF file. So I cannot convert the EPS file to MIFF since there is no miff24 device.

Are the any alternative image format similar to MIFF that can be used in GhostScript? Similar with MIFF which is faster and light.

Comment: Magick Image File Format is pretty basic. or at least the version written by Ghostscript is. I imagine pbmraw would be suitably similar. You can find the devices available by doing 'gswin64c --help'

Comment: Thank you for your comment...I actually plan to convert EPS w/ transparency to JPEG or PNG. Original plan is to use GS to convert EPS to MIFF. Then use ImageMagick to convert MIFF to JPEG/PNG.  I want MIFF because it is light weight and pretty much faster and can preserve tranparency, very useful as intermediary file for converaion. But the device is not available in GS standard installation.... GS has a lot of devices but I dont know which is pretty similar to MIFF.... I will try your suggestion using pbm raw...

Comment: EPS files cannot contain transparency, there is no transparency in the PostScript graphics model. So whatever you are doing, you can't really be ''preserving transparency'. Ghostscript can write JPEG and PNG files directly though. I'd suggest you write PNG.

Comment: sorry maybe my knowledge with EPS file is limited. But when you put a clipping path to an EPS file, GS can automatically crop this clipping path when converting to JPEG/PNG. Resulting in white background for JPEG, transparent background for PNG. —- thats why I like to make the conversion from EPS to intermediary img format like MIFF or similar img format using GS, removing the clipping path.... then from intermediary file, use Image Magick to convert to other raster img like JPeg, PNg, etc,,,,,, Thank you for your suggestion, very much appreciated.

Comment: For PNG output, Ghostscript leaves the unmarked portion as 'transparent'. That's a special for PNG output and it has nothing to do with 'PostScript' as such. Generally when rendering to file formats Ghostscript renders the unmarked portion of the page as white. So for JPEG (and MIFF as far as I know) any unmarked portion of the output will be white. To the best of my knowledge only the PNG output device leaves the unmarked portion as 'transparent'.